# Jquery input value change

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

When an event happens i want to reduce the value of an input named "shareNum" by 1.
This is what i currently use:

> $( "#shareNum" ).val(($(this).val-1)
>   );

I get a "NaN" - a non value.. something is wrong, any thoughts?

Comment: If someone is able to do the same thing on a <span> tag or any other, that would be great

Comment: It would be almost exactly the same as [@Darin's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5690106/jquery-input-value-change/5690114#5690114) posted answer, except using [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) rather than [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/). And, obviously, with sanity checks to ensure it's a valid number.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
var $shareNum = $("#shareNum");
$shareNum.val(Number($shareNum.val()) - 1);
```

And here's a [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JzQer/2/).

Comment: @Tom, could you post a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) that reproduces the problematic parts of your application?

Comment: @Tom, how does the code for your application look like then? Did you check the live demo I provided? How does your code differ?

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
$('#shareNum').val(function(i, v) {
    return v - 1;
});
```